# Kolmogorov-Smirnov One Sample Test

Tags: r, kolmogorov-smirnov

```
vect<-c(58,59,67,68,68,68,70,70,70,70,74,75,76,78,80,80,82,82,83,84,84,84,86,88,90,90,90,90,92,93,94,97,98,104,110,112)
ks.test(vect, "pnorm", 85, 15)
```

I used the following code, but it shows something like this:

```
#"Warning message:
#In ks.test(vect, "pnorm", 85, 15) :
#ties should not be present for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test"
```

and the computed answer given by the book, D, is not the same with the one given above.
I just tried to code what's given in my book.

Comment: From `?ks.test`: _"The presence of ties always generates a warning, since continuous distributions do not generate them. If the ties arose from rounding the tests may be approximately valid, but even modest amounts of rounding can have a significant effect on the calculated statistic."_. E.g. `ks.test(unique(vect), "pnorm", 85, 15)` would not give you that warning.

Comment: @lukeA it wouldn't, but it would also not give you a meaningful result. Kolmogorov-Smirnov is not suited for this case, and the normal distribution is not the best distribution to test against. Technically this is a binomial distribution, not a normal one.

Comment: @JorisMeys it turns out it's a binomial distribution. Thank you!